# How to add dash-character after every nth value from the output of a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON object which I first convert into a dictionary. In this nested dictionary, I have two sections with respective values:

1. SKU
2. Page_Limit

Now I want to programmatically add s string separator like "--" after every n-th SKU id. The n depends on the "Page_Limit". Here is the data:

```
    import json
    
    postitemsonpage = {"SKU": [
        {
          "text": "socks"
        }
          
      ],
      "Page_Limit": [
        {
          "index": 0
        },
        {
          "index": 2
   
      ]}
```

From here, I am not sure how to bring in the last piece of adding the "Page_limit" element into the output where the "--" appears after every n-th value (based on "index").

Comment: "enumerate" your for loop and use a modulus ( index % 2) calculation and print if == 0

Comment: @Trent the issue is that the %2 (i.e. grouping 2 skus into the same page) is not always the case. Sometimes index=3 which then allows to group 3 skus into the same page. Do you have any other approach which makes is dependent on Page_limit[index] rather?

Comment: hardcoding or not is irrelevant - just change the modulus calculation using a variable

Answer (score 2):

Using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with `start=1` and a set comprehension, you can get the output you want:

```
def solution(postitemsonpage):
    content = json.loads(json.dumps(postitemsonpage))
    limits = {x["index"] for x in content['Page_Limit']}
    for count, i in enumerate(content['SKU'], 1):
        sku=int(i['id'][1])
        text=i['text']
        print(sku,text)
        if count in limits:
            print("--")
```

Output:

```
0 socks
1 shoes
--
2 tshirt
3 ring
--
4 bra
5 leggins
```

Comment: @Franco Morero Wonderful! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @ee8291 - if you feel this answer is a complete answer to your question, please accept it with the checkmark, so others know this question needs no further answers (and that way, Franco Morero gets his deserved internet points as well :)